# Mail server sends random emails to different accounts

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, spam

so today i took a look at my Mercury Mail Server and noticed it was sending an awful lot of mail to a bunch of random mail addresses. I took a look at the emails and this is the original email:
在互联~网世界里，网络营销已经成为主~流营销模式，4i
如何找~到一套系统的~网络推广模式。oP
全方位推广~您的产品~或者服务。8Q
快速提~升销售业绩。让更多客~户找到你。7M
全面整理了~数百套网~络营销实战资料。xu
为您和~您的事业助~上一臂之力。h1
让成千上~万客户找到您，购买~您的产品。cI
并快~速打造自动~化营销系统。75
系统分享如~何进行推广的~实战操作。YB
让你事半~功倍，快速将营销大~计执行出来。z1
全套~资料168 元 附录是~内容，8a
扣nc扣：984108—291

BI3UCuWq

Now when i translated it, it said something about marketing in it but i dont know why these would be sending and how to stop them. Does anyone know how to stop these randomly sent email spam? Thanks in advance for the heroic person that helps me out.
-Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check your mail logs to see what user is sending the mail. Are you using SMTPAUTH and in that case, are they logged in?
- Is it possible to send e-mails through your server *without* authenticating?
- What IP address do the messages come from?
- Is it possible that a spam program may have been installed on the mail server machine, or on any other machine in your computing environment?